# Unable to connect postgres DB remotely

Tags: postgresql

Every time, when I try to connect to remote Postgres DB, I receive error:

```
 no pg_hba.conf entry for host "159.224.92.121", user "xpkzxqrkisdrjd", database "d92na0gp4bdq4", SSL off
```

I googled it and found that two config files should be updated.

Should append:

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I did it, but error still occurs, when I try to connect to remote DB.
Local DB work fine.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Maybe it will be useful. I have installed postgres using homebrew.
For restarting postgres server I use:

`brew services postgres restart`

Comment: Told the server to reload configuration?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I continued to google this issue and finally found the answer. You should use SSL option.

Please, check this link:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205996299/comments/206373089

Answer (score 1):

Two items to help you on the way:

- `pg_hba.conf` is processed from top to bottom, so if the incoming connection matches an earlier line, that entry will be used.
- Set `log_connections = on` in `postgresql.conf` and reload. Then, after a connection attempt has failed, look into the log file for the reason. Recent PostgreSQL versions will also tell you which `pg_hba.conf` line was used.

Comment: Thank you for notes, they are useful! But it didn't help me

Comment: Well, since you didn't tell *anything* about your setup and how you are trying to connect, all one can give is general help.